# How are adjacent brace expansions actually parsed?

Tags: bash

Adjacent [brace expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion)
result in the cartesian product of their elements:

```
$ echo {a,b}{c,d}{e,f}
ace acf ade adf bce bcf bde bdf
```

I want to know if this is a special feature of brace expansions, or if it arises from the following rule, or any other rule documented in `man bash`:

> Patterns to be brace expanded take the form of an optional preamble, followed
>   by either a series of comma-separated strings or a sequence expression between
>   a pair of braces, followed by an optional postscript. The preamble is prefixed
>   to each string contained within the braces, and the postscript is then appended
>   to each resulting string, expanding left to right.

If it does arise from this rule, how exactly does this work?

It seems to me that you'd need a
separate rule such as:

*When the preamble is itself a brace expansion, each element
is expanded against the brace expansion to the right, and then those results
are concatenated in left to right order*

That is, `{a,b}{c,d}` is the concatenation of `a{c,d}` and `b{c,d}`.

But I don't see any such rule in the `man bash` description of "Brace Expansions"
that explicitly justifies this behavior.

Am I missing it?

Comment: I imagine it's just left to right. `{a,b}{c,d}{e,f}` is a brace expansion `{a,b}`with no prefix and a postscript of `{c,d}{e,f}`, resulting in `a{c,d}{e,f} b{c,d}{e,f}`. Each of those two brace expansions are expanded, resulting in `ac{e,f} ad{e,f} bc{e,f} bd{e,f}`, and each of those *four* are expanded to the final result `ace acf ade adf bce bcf bde bdf`.

Comment: This probably answers your question, it's quite in-depth: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402315/nested-brace-expansion-mystery-in-bash

Comment: (The missing rule in my interpretation would be that brace expansion is applied recursively to the *result* of any brace expansion until no brace expressions remain. This rule is somewhat implied by the fact that nested brace expressions are explicitly supported.)

Comment: @chepner is it though?  adjacent BEs are not nested.  so afaict the required rule is missing

Comment: No, but it seems very likely to me that expanding the outer BE produces a series of brace expressions to be further expanded. That is, something like `{a{b,c,d},e{f,g}}` first expands to `a{b,c,d} e{f,g}`. (`{ab ac ad,ef eg}` itself is not a brace expansion, which makes outside-in a simpler explanation for how it expands.)

Comment: @chepner i agree it’s likely implemented that way (or something close).  my question is whether or not it’s fair to call this undocumented given the text in man bash

Comment: I'd say *underdocumented* rather than *undocumented*. Keep in mind that the `bash` documentation is informative at best, *definitely* not *normative*. It's not meant to be a specification.

Comment: feel free to add that as an answer and i’ll accept unless someone else provides evidence to the contrary